# Show exceptions and chttpexceptions in modal yii2

Tags: exception, yii2, modal-dialog

Hey guys im making an website and i need show an error (exception or chttpexception) when this happens in a modal.

Actually the modal displays empty but the console shows the error.

How i can solve this?

Thanks.

**This is what happen now:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV61O.png

**I need this:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPfKi.png

**My controller actions:**

```
public function actionMomios($id)
{
    $this->findModel(1000); //this number is for the error its an ID
}
```

**This is the function who throws the error:**

```
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = Partido::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('El partido no se encuentra registrado'); // This is the exception i need to show

}
```

**This is the code who calls the modal (its in a gridview):**

```
 'momios' => function($url,$model,$key){
        $btn = Html::button("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-usd'></span>",[
            'value'=>Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('partido/momios?id='.$key),
            'class'=>'momioedit grid-action btn btn-success',
            'title'=>'Modificar momios'
        ]);
        return $btn;

        },
```

**My modal in the view:**

```
<?php

Modal::begin([
        'header' => '<h4>Editar Momio</h4>',
        'id'     => 'modalmomio',
        'size'   => 'modal-lg',

]);

echo "<div id='momiocontent'></div>";

Modal::end();

?>
```

**My JS:**

```
$('.momioedit').click(function(){
     $('#modalmomio').modal('show')
        .find('#momiocontent')
         .load($(this).attr('value'));

});
```

Comment: are these exceptions are against ajax calls?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam thanks for answer, yeah its called in a button from a gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap your code inside a `try{}catch(){}` block inside the `actionMomios($id)` that calls the `findModel()` method like below.

```
public function actionMomios($id)
{
    try{
        $this->findModel(1000); //this number is for the error its an ID
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i apply with a little changes and this work, thanks so much <3

Comment: Good to hear that @ErnestoEspaña